# Insert animated gif on a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an animated gif file.

How can I get this animation to appear on Sheet1 and then close when my macro is complete?

I tried adding the gif as a picture then adding a webbrowser command window and command button.

I wrote the following command button code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate1 ("C:\Users\smorfett\Desktop\progress.gif")
End Sub
```

I get

> 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: Downvote as, per the downvote mouseover, "this question does not show any research effort". Have you tried recording a macro while manually adding the animation?

Comment: I cannot get the animation to work ... I edited my question to include an explanation of my efforts so far.

Comment: - 1 Lacks reasearch! Commonly asked question. Answer can be easily found in Google

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution ...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

WebBrowser1.Navigate "C:\Users\smorfett\Desktop\progress.gif"

End Sub
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View > Toolbars > Control Toolbox
Activate Design mode
Choose the last button (the one with a hammer), then select Microsoft Web Browser
Draw a frame for the image
Disable Design mode and the toolbar
Paste the following code in the VBA editor:

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() WebBrowser1.Navigate "X:complete path image.GIF" End Sub

Source:
https://ccm.net/faq/1402-inserting-an-animated-gif-in-excel